# How do I get Sails.js to query an existing database?

Tags: sql-server, node.js, jdbc, sails.js, waterline

There's a dev database already set up for another project.  I'm trying to create a sails.js server to connect to this database and act as a RESTful API.  I'm also using [SQL Workbench](http://www.sql-workbench.net/) with the profile below to connect to the database and verify my query statements.  On that tool, I'm able to send queries like `select top 10 * from advisor` and get the data I expect in response.

[image: SQL Workbench Connection Profile]

My connection configuration in sails.js seems to be alright, since I'm able to start the server.  I've gotten simple static actions to work, like `hi: function (req, res) { return res.send("Hi there!"); }`.  However, I can't figure out what to do to get a response from the database served by sails.  My goal (at this point) is to have `http://localhost:1337/advisor` return JSON for the results of `select top 10 * from advisor`.

I initially tried using the freshly-generated model.  Then, I tried adding attributes to the model file.  Then, I tried adding my own code to the controller.  In each case, the browser never received a response.  At the end, I tested `/advisor/list` to run my own code and it doesn't look like the query() callback was ever executed.  In case it's the first question, I have run `npm install sails-sqlserver` and I've double-checked that my host, db, username, & password are identical to what was used in Workbench.

#### connections.js

```
sqlserver: {
  adapter: 'sails-sqlserver',
  user: 'myusername',
  password: 'mypassword',
  host: 'mysubdomain.mydomain.net:1433',
  database: 'frontofficedev'
}
```

#### models.js

```
module.exports.models = {
  connection: 'sqlserver',
  migrate: 'safe'
};
```

#### api\models\Advisor.js

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    advcode: 'string',
    advname: 'string',
    'adv-default': 'boolean',
    "user-id": 'string',
    "pc-code": 'string',
    "adv-tag": 'string',
    "is-group": 'boolean',
    "trade-grouping": 'string',
    AdvisorId: 'int',
    orgcode: 'string',
    BranchId: 'int',
    OrdPrnBranchId: 'int',
    zdec1: 'float',
    zdec2: 'float',
    zchar1: 'string',
    zchar2: 'string',
    zchar3: 'string',
    zchar4: 'string',
    AdvStatus: 'string'
  }
};
```

#### api\controllers

```
module.exports = {
  hi: function (req, res) {
    return res.send("Hi there!");
  },
  list: function (req, res) {
    var myQuery = "select TOP 10 * from advisor";

    sails.log.debug("Query :", myQuery);

    console.log(Advisor);

    Advisor.query(myQuery, function (err, advisors){
      console.log(advisors);
      console.log(err);
      if(err || !advisors.rows.length){
        return res.json({"status": 0, "error": err});
      }
      else{
        return res.json(advisors);
      }
    });
  }
};
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?  Is JDBC causing problems?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is [this](https://github.com/CraZySacX/node-jdbc) a step in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My colleague spotted the problem.  The port that database lives on needs to be a separate attribute in sails' connection.js (instead of including it in the host string).  No need for extra libraries, like node-jdbc.

*config/connections.js*

```
sqlserver: {
  adapter: 'sails-sqlserver',
  user: 'myusername',
  password: 'mypassword',
  host: 'mysubdomain.mydomain.net',
  port: 1433,
  database: 'frontofficedev'
}
```

After making that change, I was able to delete all my custom code from the controller and almost everything from the model (I still need to specify a primary key, since sails looks for `id` by default and the database was using `AdvisorId`.

*api/models/Advisor.js*

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    AdvisorId: {primaryKey: true}
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Im assuming you've already run: npm install sails-sqlserver --save

You have to specify your connection and the table you will be using in the model, the variables in the model should match with your DB variables, like this:

**api\models\Advisor.js**

```
    module.exports = {
    schema: true,
    connection: 'sqlserver',
    tableName: 'yourTableName',
    attributes: {
    advcode:{
       type: 'string',
       primaryKey: true //if this is a primary key
    }, 
    advname:{
       type: 'string'
    },
    'adv-default':{
       type: 'boolean'
  }
};
```

In your controller you can use the Sails ORM waterline like this:

**api\controllers**

```
module.exports = {
  list: function (req, res) {
    Advisor.query('SELECT * FROM advisor', function(err, results) {
      if (err) {
        res.send(400);
      } else {
        res.send(results);
      }
    });
  }
};
```

Where Advisor is the model.

For more specific information about models and ORM waterline i recommend you read the sails docs: http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models

Comment: Yeah, I've been reading that documentation, but I hadn't tried setting schema and tableName yet; thanks.  Unfortunately, your changes gave me the same results as before: the callback defined in query() never gets executed.  (This was after fillining in `attributes` to match the database and correcting the closing brackets at the bottom of the controller.)